# Spring MVC 3.1 RedirectAttributes is not working

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement RedirectAttributes feature in Spring MVC 3.1-Release

I'm sending simple form to Post URL and would like to see the the value I'm sending in redirect:

my Controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/index.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView indexView(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
    return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greetings.action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView startTask(@RequestParam("firstName") String firstName,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("redirectAttributes.firstName", firstName);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("success.html"));
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/success.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView successView(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("success");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Now my Servlet XML looks like this:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.vanilla.flashscope.controllers" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My problem is that in success.html view redirectAttributes is empty.

```
<body>
<h5>${redirectAttributes.firstName} </h5> 
</body>
```

Prints nothing.

Comment: I have the same. If you get the solution let me know, please.

Comment: Yes, I did. I wrote some thoughts about it on my community site, hope it will help you. http://goo.gl/Qbym2

Comment: Tks Danny. I was looping aroung the same problem. The key was returning a string and not a ModelAndView, seems strange but works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not work because You are using ModelAndView as a return value.

See JIRA Issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8968

Comment: :facepalm: What should be returned instead?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to remove "redirectAttributes." from the key name"

Instead of:

```
     redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("redirectAttributes.firstName", firstName);
```

Do this:

```
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("firstName", firstName);
```

Comment: Hi, it works perfectly with or without this prefix in in key name.