# difference between Spring 2.5 and Spring 3.1: ModelAndView

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring2.5 we write controller like as follows:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController{

 @RequestMapping(value="/welcome",method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");
    model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

    return model;
}
```

}

In Spring 3.1:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/welcome",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcomeString(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("message", "hello world);
    return "hello";

}
```

printwelcomeString() function return a String instead of ModelAndView.

Can any one explain it more?
How it is going to work? 
How hello.jsp get model to display?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring 3.5 is not released yet I hope you are meaning Spring 3.1.

`return ModelAndView` is an old style code writing, used in Spring 2.0. In spring 3.0 add later you can return both ModelAndView or nameView either.

I recommend you to return always String (view Name) because some advanced features of Spring MVC will not work properly:

Example:
[Spring MVC 3.1 RedirectAttributes is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637043/spring-mvc-3-1-redirectattributes-is-not-working)